ACME console client on windows non IIS web server
Windows 10 + hMailserver + Abyss web server (five domains)
Trying use console win-acme.exe to set-up ACME to issue certificates to encrypt SMTP communication. Download Win-ACME console app. Started it by
wacs.exe --validation selfhosting


Step: choose "Create certificate (default settings)"
Step: "Manual Input"
Step: Entered comma separated list of domain names

In fourth step, program behave differently depending if its started as Administrator or not. If started as regular user, it ask "Save verification files on (network) path" and accept path to local directory. Then ask for "Copy default web.config to the .well-known directory" (answered [default] no) and than tell me "Store plugin CertificateStore not available: Run as administrator to allow certificate store access".
But when try to run program as Admin, it ask to confirm "Terms of use", than ask for email address and start printing lines:
Plugin Manual generated source domain1.com with 5 identifiers
     Plugin Single created 1 order
     Cached order has status invalid, discarding
     [domain2.com] Authorizing...
     [domain2.com] Authorizing using http-01 validation (SelfHosting)
     Unable to activate listener, this may be because of insufficient rights or a non-Microsoft webserver using port 80
     An error occured while commiting validation configuration: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
     An error occured during post-validation cleanup: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListener'.
     [domain1.com] Deactivating pending authorization
     [domain2.com] Deactivating pending authorization
     [domain3.com] Deactivating pending authorization
     [domain4.com] Deactivating pending authorization
     [domain5.com] Deactivating pending authorization
Create certificate failed, retry? (y/n*)

Have zero experince, expect I will just specify some URL on my web server where I put some specific content for validation? What am I doing wrong? Why it behave differently under different credentials?
